# How to show filter-selected items in URL in Drupal?

Tags: url

Page allows for a selected filter, but does not change the url. but i need to know How to show filter-selected items in URL in Drupal.

tried to use and old page and url re-direct to but didnt work

i am NOT programmer and really have no knowledge of drupal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.